# Create all possible combinations with a constraint

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

**Package box** (T1, T2,T3,T4,). -->  Pick 1 out of 4

BATS :

**Baseball bats** (B1-a, B1-b, B1-c, B1-d) -->  Pick 1 out of 4

**Cricket bats**(B2-p, B2-q) -->  Pick 1 out of 2

**Hockey bats**(B3-i, B3-j, B3-k) --> Pick 1 out of 3

**Ice-Hockey bats** (B4-x, B4-y, B4-z) -->  Pick 1 out of 3

HELMETS:

**Baseball Helmets** (H1-a,H1-b, H1-c) -->  Pick 1 out of 3

**Cricket helmets** (H2-p, H2-q) --> Pick 1 out of 2

We are creating combination using 1 of each item, **so 7 items in 1 combination**:

1 Package box, 1 Baseball bat, 1 Cricket bat, 1 Hockey bat, 1 Ice-hockey bat,1 Baseball helmet& 1 Cricket helmet

**Example combinations made of 7 items**:

**C1**= T1, B1-a, B2-p, B3-i, B4-x, H1-a, H2-p

**C2**=T1,B1-b, B2-p,B3-j, B4-y, H1-b, H2-q

...so on

Question:
**How many different combinations could be created with the constraint that maximum 2  exact bats could be common in any 2 combinations ?**
In other words , out of all the possible different combinations, **if you randomly pick ANY 2 combinations** and **IF they have exact same bats common** , then maximum number of bats that could be common **would be 2.**

Example of 2 combinations with common bats :

C12=T2, B1-a, **B2-p**, B3-i, **B4-x**, H1-a, H2-p

C23=T4, B1-d, **B2-p**,  B3-k, **B4-x**, H1-c, H2-p

There **cannot be** 2 combinations like this:

C13=T2, B1-a, **B2-p, B3-i, B4-x**, H1-a, H2-p

C24=T4, B1-d, **B2-p,  B3-i, B4-x**, H1-c, H2-p

If possible please provide the formula used.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: off topic question: who has chosen the names of the objects, e.g. B4-x for an Ice-Hockey bat. Did you do this or are these the names from the original question?

Comment: "B4-x for an Ice-Hockey bat"- made up name for the series.    "..names from the original question" - no there is no original question, I formulated this problem myself :-)

Comment: I think a nomenclature like "Bi-1" for an Ice-Hockey bat would make it easier to read and  handle this problem.

Comment: @zennni did my answer help you ? if so , can you acept it ?

Answer (score 1):

For zero bats common = $3 \times 1 \times 2 \times 2 = 12$ new bats

For one bats common = $(1 \times 2 \times 2 ) + (3 \times 2 \times 2 ) + (3 \times 1 \times 2 ) + (3 \times 1 \times 2) = 28$ new bats

For two bats common = $(2 \times 2 ) +(1 \times 2) + (1\times 2 ) + (3 \times 2) + (3 \times 2) + (3 \times 1)=23$ new bats

For the fist combos = $$4 \times 4 \times 2 \times 3 \times 3 \times 3 \times 2=1728$$
possible combs there are.

For the second combos = $$4\times (12+28 +23 ) \times 3 \times 2 =1512$$

Result  = $$1728 \times 1512 = 260928 $$ possible combos

NOTE = I assumed that restriction is only over bats , the other items can repeat

Comment: First of all Thanks a bunch  Bulbasaur . Sorry I know absolutely zilch about combinatorics , permutations and combinations but I just used some random comparison logic and had a question about - "For the second combos =
4×(12+28+23)×3×2=1512" . Please refer the fig: https://snipboard.io/lKwExr.jpg Should there be an additional  'times 4' for 'Package box' ? Thanks again

Comment: "NOTE = I assumed that restriction is only over bats , the other items can repeat" - that assumption is absolutely correct!

Comment: @zennni you are welcome zennni ! $4$ is already for the package box , you do not need to add anything

Comment: off course there is x 4 , feel like an idiot. Thanks again !

Comment: @zennni you are welcome ! if you do not understand another things  ,you can ask again..

Comment: @ Bulbasaur A side questions: I am not a software developer either , so was wondering  can a software program be developed ,for your math model, that  will spit out all 260,928 possible combos in a CSV file?
I could seek help from some developer. I was looking at Github libraries , example this PHP one :
https://github.com/markrogoyski/math-php

Can a library like this one ( or any other in some different language) make it little easier for developer to build program for your math model ?

Thanks

Comment: @zennni unfortunatelly, i do not about programming anything